# Alert is not function error is console

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm integrating otp functionality in ionic 3 project. When I send the otp I'm receiving the otp but not redirecting to the otp receive the page because of this error.

Below is console error
Getting below error on sending otp

> ERROR TypeError: alert is not a function
>       at SafeSubscriber._error (home.ts:45)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
>       at SafeSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:197)
>       at Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
>       at Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:82)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1556)
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)

I'm receiving the otp but page is not redirecting to the otp receive page because of this error

My code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Platform, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {OtpReceivePage} from '../otp-receive/otp-receive';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    mobile = '';

    constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController,
                public http: Http,
                public navCtrl: NavController) {
    }

    sendOTP() {
        if (this.mobile.length != 12) {
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'Mobile Number Required!',
                subTitle: 'Please enter your 10 digit mobile number with 91 country code!',
                buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
        }
        else {
            this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/nexmosms/send-sms.php')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
                    this.navCtrl.push(OtpReceivePage, {mobileno: this.mobile})
                }, (err) => {
                    alert("failed");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rename `let alert` and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You second alert is not defined

```
(err) => {  alert("failed");});
```

You need to replace it like what you deed in the first one.

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'failed'
                buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
```

But then again I recommend you create a function `alert( message:string){}` so that you don't repeat code.